# Cache TFS login credentials for git-tf

Tags: git-tf

I use git and git-tf at my job, but every time I perform any command with git-tf I have to  enter my login credentials.  Is there a way to cache my TFS login credentials for git-tf so I won't have to enter them every time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Kerberos and have a trust relationship with the Active Directory domain that your TFS server is on, you need not enter any password, git-tf will use your Kerberos ticket to authenticate.  This, of course, will only work with on-premises servers; it will not work with Team Foundation Service.

To cache your username and password for the repository, you can set these in your `.git/config`:

```
git config git-tf.server.username myusername
git config git-tf.server.password mypassword
```

However, do note that this will store your password in *plain text*, which is why Kerberos is preferred.  I am interested in adding support for the git credential storage mechanisms, but this does not yet exist.