# Add a local user to git-tfs

Tags: git, tfs

for one of my projects I have to use TFS. For that purpose I have installed git-tfs.
Everything works pretty fine - Now I want to add my user that is defined in TFS and which is different from the user I have defined on Github or Bitbucket to that specific repository so that I dont have to enter my username and password everytime I do a `git tf push` or `git tf pull`.

I tried to add a local `.gitconfig` to the root directory of that repository and I tried to execute `git config user.name "myname"` but neither works. Still I have to enter my name and password all the time.

Comment: Can you clarify?  Is your question about `git-tf` or `git-tfs`?  What operating system are you using?

Comment: I got the issue solved via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16595040/cache-tfs-login-credentials-for-git-tf/16595798#16595798